# Regex to remove word from XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

I need help writing regex to remove a word using XSLT.

I need to change the output of my XML file's "detailpath" from:

/events/262/26207

...to simply:

262/26207

The XSL is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="detailpath"/>
```

How can I remove "/events/"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex pattern would simply be `'/events/'`

You can use it in an [XSLT 2.0 replace()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function call:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(detailpath,'/events/','')"/>
```

> function returns the xs:string that is
>   obtained by replacing each
>   non-overlapping substring of $input
>   that matches the given $pattern with
>   an occurrence of the $replacement
>   string.

You can optionally specify [flags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags)

> ```
> fn:replace( $input     as xs:string?,
>             $pattern   as xs:string,
>             $replacement   as xs:string) as xs:string
>
> fn:replace( $input     as xs:string?,
>             $pattern   as xs:string,
>             $replacement   as xs:string,
>             $flags     as xs:string) as xs:string
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Do note that for your example (starting string) you could alse use this XPath 1.0 expression:

```
substring(detailpath, 9 * starts-with(detailpath,'/events/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another XPath 1.0 solution (assuming there is only one instance of the string to replace) that would work regardless of where the text fragment is in the string:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(detailpath,'/events/'), 
                             substring-after(detailpath,'/events/'))" />
```

Answer (score -1):

echo /events/262/26207 | sed -e 's|/events/||g'

This works in bash on Solaris and, with tweaking, should work in PHP, Javascript and Perl, to my knowledge.

Comment: I think he wanted an XSLT solution.