# Convert XSLT 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: xslt

I need help converting an XSLT 1.0 file to 2.0 (so I can use the XSLT 2.0 replace() function call).

I've Googled, searched different books and SO with no success. I tried changing `version="1.0"` to `2.0` and changing `html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"` to simply `html` but this all just results in XSLTProcessor errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" encoding="ISO-8859-1" /> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<xsl:element name="meta">
<xsl:attribute name="name">description</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="EventList/title"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="link"><xsl:attribute name="rel">alternate</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="type">application/rss+xml</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="title">RSS</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="EventList/rssURL"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
</head>
<body>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="EventList" />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="EventList">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="Event">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Event"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <div class="eventItem">
    <div class="eventItemText">
     <p>There are currently no events posted for this category.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<!-- List -->
<xsl:template match="Event">
 <li>
  <!-- Title -->
  <xsl:if test="eventStatus = 2"><xsl:value-of select="eventStatusString"/> - </xsl:if>
  <xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href">http://events.stanford.edu/e/e/?d=<xsl:value-of select="replace(detailpath,'/events/','')"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="eventID"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="rel">external</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <!-- Date and time -->
  <xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href">http://events.stanford.edu/e/details.php?detailpath=<xsl:value-of select="detailpath"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="rel">external</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="repeatRuleID &gt; 0">
     Ongoing <xsl:value-of select="repeatRuleText"/> from <xsl:value-of select="beginDate"/> through <xsl:value-of select="repeatUntilDate"/>.
     <xsl:if test="repeatRuleID=99">See details for exact dates and times.</xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:if test="string(beginDay)"><xsl:value-of select="beginDay"/>, </xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select="beginDate"/>.
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
   <xsl:if test="repeatRuleID!=99">
    <xsl:if test="string(beginTime)">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="beginTime"/>.
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:element>
  <!-- Location -->
  <xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href">http://events.stanford.edu/e/details.php?detailpath=<xsl:value-of select="detailpath"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="rel">external</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="locationText"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I'm not sure - it's being processed by PHP (version 5.2.6).

Comment: I believe PHP uses libxslt and that doesn't support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the necessary steps to use xslt code with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Changing version="1.0" to "2.0" is actually the last thing you should do. If you leave it at version="1.0" and put it through a 2.0 processor, the processor will run in "backwards compatibility mode" which means it's very unlikely you will trip over any of the incompatibilities introduced in 2.0 - and this doesn't stop you using new 2.0 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In addition to changing the `version` attribute to `'2.0'`, you need to feed your XSLT 2.0 code to an XSLT 2.0 processor**.

At present, some of the XSLT 2.0 processors I use are:

- **[Saxon 9.x](http://www.saxonica.com)**
- **[XQSharp 2.0](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/)**
- **[AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html)** (XMLSpy)

**Do note** that an existing XSLT 1.0 code may behave differently under XSLT 2.0 -- the most obvious differences are that `<xsl:value-of>` no longer produces the string value of only the first node from a node-set, and that in XSLT 2.0 the dreaded RTF type has been eliminated, so no `xxx:node-set()` extension function is needed/provided.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check the non normative XSLT 2.0 Appendix J [Changes from XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#changes) .

> This section lists all known cases
>   where a stylesheet that was valid
>   (produced no errors) under XSLT 1.0,
>   and whose behavior was fully specified
>   by XSLT 1.0, will produce different
>   results under XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

While you're converting the code, you should get rid of those ugly disable-output-escaping="yes" attributes. They are almost certainly not wanted. The use of this attribute usually indicates that it was written by a novice with a poor understanding of the language. This also applies to the use of verbose constructs like

```
<xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href">http://events.stanford.edu/e/e/?d=<xsl:value-of select="replace(detailpath,'/events/','')"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="eventID"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="rel">external</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:element>
```

that could be replaced by the much more readable

```
<a href="http://events.stanford.edu/e/e/?d={replace(detailpath,'/events/','')}"
   id="{@eventID}" rel="external">
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</a>
```

Generally, some refactoring is long overdue for this code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I just discovered that my php server is limited to XSLT 1.0.

I did find an XSLT 1.0 [solution for the replace function][1] (thanks @Alejandro):

substring(detailpath, 9 * starts-with(detailpath,'/events/'))

I tried incorporating this function with your revised code but keep getting various errors. How can I simplify my link code with this function? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754332/regex-to-remove-word-from-xslt