# Converting stylesheet from XSLT 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xslt 1.0 stylesheet which needs to be converted to xslt 2.0.

I found this question here: [Convert XSLT 1.0 to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762809/convert-xslt-1-0-to-2-0) which deals with the same issue.

According to that changing version attribute to 2.0 would do the trick. But is that the only thing which needs to be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the choice of strategy for conversion depends on how good a set of regression tests you have.

If you have a good set of regression tests, or if the consequences of introducing an error are not severe, then I would recommend the following steps:

(a) change the version attribute to 2.0

(b) run your test cases using an XSLT 2.0 processor and see if they work

(c) examine any test discrepancies and identify their cause (perhaps 80% of the time it will work correctly first time with no discrepancies).

If you don't have good tests or if you can't afford to take any risks, then you might need a more cautious strategy. (The ultimate in caution, of course, is the "don't change anything" strategy - stick with 1.0). Perhaps the best advice in this case is to start the conversion project by writing more test cases. At the very least, collect together a sample of the source documents you are currently processing, and the output that is generated for these source documents, and then use a file comparison tool to compare the output you get after conversion.

There are a few incompatibilities between 1.0 and 2.0; the one you are most likely to encounter is that xsl:value-of (and many other constructs) in 1.0 ignore all nodes in the supplied input sequence after the first, whereas XSLT 2.0 outputs all the nodes in the supplied sequence. There are two ways of dealing with this problem. Either (my recommendation) identify the places where this problem occurs, and fix them, usually by changing select="X" to select="X[1]"; or change the version attribute on the xsl:stylesheet back to version="1.0", which causes the XSLT 2.0 processor to run in backwards compatibility mode. The disadvantage of relying on backwards compatibility mode is that you lose the benefits of the stronger type-checking in XSLT 2.0, which makes complex stylesheet code much easier to debug.

In my experience the problems you encounter in conversion are more likely to depend on processor/implementation changes than on W3C language changes. Your code might be using vendor-defined extension functions that aren't supported in the 2.0 processor, or it might be relying on implementation-defined behaviour such as collating sequences that varies from one processor to another. I have seen code, for example, that relied on the specific format of the output produced by generate-id(), which is completely implementation-dependent.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. I am very happy to have your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

["XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 2.0", §J, "Changes from XSLT 1.0 (Non-Normative)"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#changes) lists most the differences between XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 that you need to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks, what I need is to convert from 1.0 to 2.0. I need to know what I should do for transformation.

Comment: Yes, I have read it in the past. I want the simple steps of conversion. Conversion does not require all the differences. And I have read Michael Kay's book to a certain extent. He is in stachoverflow and hope he sees this. :) Thank you.